# Compute quaternion from angular velocity Twist

Tags: ros-melodic, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using ROS melodic with kitti bag file.
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on i7 , with kernel 5.3.0-42-generic.
I get the odometry of a Kitti bag file with viso2_ros.
I want to predict the poses of the robot. To compute the next pose I should compute the quaternion of the robot. How can I compute it from angular velocity?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350618/compute-quaternion-from-angular-velocity-twist/) by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quaternions are the angular part of a non-moving pose. Angular velocity is a measurement of how fast an object is rotating about a certain point.

If you're looking for prediction, I suggest using forward Euler.

```
theta_t = theta_t-1 + omega_theta * dtheta/dt
```

Where theta is an angle and omega is the angular velocity.

You'll likely want to convert between quaternion and euler notation, in which ros has the following functions

```
import tf
quat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)
(roll, pitch, yaw) = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(quat)
```

---

Originally posted by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) with karma: 71 on 2020-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Younès](https://answers.ros.org/users/29249/youn%C3%A8s/) on 2020-04-25**:
Thank you. It works fine.